# SSIS add values to column without inserting new rows

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I am trying to write into my_table, in column ABC values to rows where id match.
My issue now is that I'm adding new rows, which is not what I want. I want to write on the row when col id from my_table matches id with my query.

I tried using a lookup but so far unsuccessfully.

[image]

whats the best approach you would suggest?

Comment: You could use an execute sql task which runs a parameterized update statement for each row, or you could write all the data to a staging table and then run an execute sql task which merges the rows from the staging table to the target (update with join). If you do the latter I would personally wrap the logic in a stored procedure and call that, if possible.

Comment: would like to build this using ssis tools. avoid sql execs

Comment: An execute sql task is a task in SSIS. You cannot use a destination component to do an update, since a destination component is always accepting inserts. If you want to get really fancy what you can do is create "pretend" destination table with an instead-of-insert trigger on it. As far as SSIS knows it is inserting into this destination table, but under the covers SQL Server turns it into an update. This approach does come with some gotchas. If you want more details let me know.

Comment: You might look at using the derived column transformation. It will allow you to add a new column or replace an existing column with your updated value.

Comment: Are you trying to update rows already in the destination table (OLE DB Destination)? Or is it that the destination is empty when you start executing the package, but Lookup is duplicating rows (it wouldn't) coming from the 'input rows from query'?

Comment: @tinazmu, column i want to update is empty

Comment: Not the column, the table; does it have rows before you run the package

Comment: yes, contains data already from some steps above in the ETL

Comment: You can set the column value with lookup in that upstream ETL, which populates the table